# Spring 4 ,the custom messageConverter don`t work

Tags: java, spring, jackson2

I want to use @RestController annotation & jackson2, but the response JSON (include java.util.Date) always return Timestamp;I did the following things, but it dose not work...

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean id="customJsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="customObjectMapper"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>



public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper{


public CustomObjectMapper(){
    this.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    this.setDateFormat(df);
}
```

}

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/reports")
public class ReportController extends...
```

debug and find there is only defualt 5 MessageConverters...
[the screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VdwL.png)

Comment: MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter is registered as fourth MessageConverter. Check if it references your CustomObjectMapper as expected.

Comment: No..I checked.The dateformat configuration is the default value. `But the  CustomObjectMappers constructor  have been called during the initialization`,So I guess it`s probably that I used more than one InitializingBean ,and it covers the original configuration or other reasons... ...........I Just have no idea!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it using annotations

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CustomObjectMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    public JacksonConfiguration(CustomObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the customObjectMapper with the XML Configuration。